# How to add custom JS to the Froala Django framework

Tags: javascript, django, froala

I am using the Django implementation of Froala (https://github.com/froala/django-froala-editor/tree/master/froala_editor).

This means Froala is implemented via the Django framework using `views.py`, `models.py` and `forms.py` rather than initialisation as an inline Javascript.

In this implementation I am able to pass options to Froala via `forms.py`. E.g:

```
class PageForm(forms.ModelForm):
    content = forms.CharField(widget=FroalaEditor(options={
        'dragInline': False,
        'toolbarButtons': [['bold', 'italic', 'subscript', 'superscript'], ['indent', 'outdent', 'formatOL', 'formatUL']],
    }))
```

However, if I want to implement custom events to the editor, such as this https://www.froala.com/wysiwyg-editor/examples/drop-content example of drop content, how can I do this via Django?.

Usually I would add the following code, but the editor is already initialised via Django templates so it's not clear how I would proceed.

```
<script>
    var dragCallback = function (e) {
      e.dataTransfer.setData('Text', this.id);
    };

    // For Firefox to work.
    document.querySelector('#drag-smile').addEventListener('dragstart', dragCallback);
    document.querySelector('#drag-text').addEventListener('dragstart', dragCallback);

    new FroalaEditor('div#froala-editor', {
      events: {
        initialized: function () {
          var editor = this;

          editor.events.on('drop', function (dropEvent) {
            // Focus at the current posisiton.
            editor.markers.insertAtPoint(dropEvent.originalEvent);
            var $marker = editor.$el.find('.fr-marker');
            $marker.replaceWith(FroalaEditor.MARKERS);
            editor.selection.restore();

            // Save into undo stack the current position.
            if (!editor.undo.canDo()) editor.undo.saveStep();

            // Insert HTML.
            if (dropEvent.originalEvent.dataTransfer.getData('Text') == 'drag-smile') {
              editor.html.insert('<span class="fr-emoticon fr-emoticon-img" style="background: url(https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/emojione/2.0.1/assets/svg/1f600.svg)">&nbsp;</span>');
            }
            else {
              editor.html.insert('Hello!');
            }

            // Save into undo stack the changes.
            editor.undo.saveStep();

            // Stop event propagation.
            dropEvent.preventDefault();
            dropEvent.stopPropagation();

            // Firefox show cursor.
            if (editor.core.hasFocus() && editor.browser.mozilla) {
              editor.events.disableBlur();
              setTimeout(function () {
                editor.$el.blur().focus();
                editor.events.enableBlur();
              }, 0);
            }

            return false;
          }, true);
        }
      }
    })
</script>
```

Comment: `editor = $("#{{ form.your_field.id_for_label }}").data('froala.editor')` will get you the editor object.   Then I think you can do `editor.events.on( ... `.